# not redeclaring variable in php

Tags: php, mysql

I`ve got problem, my variable $x is not redeclaring to "english". Where is the problem? Thanks a lot:

```
<?php
// assign language or default english
$x = $lang_detected;
$language_table = '
<form id="lang_detected" method="post" 
  action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '">
  <input type="button" value="' . $x . '" onclick = "displayLangList()" style="width:200px;display:block;margin:auto;" />
  <input type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>';

$possible_lang = mysqli_query($con, 
'SELECT name2 FROM page WHERE name2 = "' . $lang_detected . '"');

if (mysqli_num_rows($possible_lang) > 0 ) {
  echo $language_table;
} else {
  $x = 'english';
  echo $language_table;
}  
?>
```

even if i do:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($possible_lang) > 0 ) {
  $x = "bla bla";
  echo $language_table;
} else {
  $x = 'english';
  echo $language_table;
}
```

$x still holds the value:

```
$x = $lang_detected;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct a variable using other variables those values are baked in, as-is, at that exact moment. There's no way to defer evaluation other than to wrap that into a function.

That is:

```
$x = 'a';
$y = '(' . $x . ')';
$x = 'b';
```

In this case `$y` is, and will remain, `(a)` even though `$x` has changed. There's no binding difference.

In your code you can always move that content down and avoid the duplication:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($possible_lang) > 0 ) {
  $x = "bla bla";
} else {
  $x = 'english';
}

echo '<form ...language table'.$x.'...';
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, you could use a function.

```
<?php
// assign language or default english
$x = $lang_detected;

$possible_lang = mysqli_query($con, 
'SELECT name2 FROM page WHERE name2 = "' . $lang_detected . '"');

if (mysqli_num_rows($possible_lang) > 0 ) {
  echo getLanguageTable($x);
} else {
  $x = 'english';
  echo getLanguageTable($x);
}

function getLanguageTable($x) {
    return '
    <form id="lang_detected" method="post" 
      action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '">
      <input type="button" value="' . $x . '" onclick = "displayLangList()" style="width:200px;display:block;margin:auto;" />
      <input type="submit" value="ok" />
    </form>';

}
```